# Bootstrap 4 & Phpmailer form upload file

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, phpmailer

I think it's quite simple to realize but i really dont know where to start. What i would like is an option in  the form where people can add an image or other file.

Ive added this in my bootstrap form:

```
<!--attachments-->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="attachment">Attachment</label>                                            
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile">
</div>
```

So far so good i guess. But it wont send because there has to be something added in my phpmailer / send.php file. This is the script which i use now:

```
    <?php
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    // Controleren of het formulier is verzonden dmv submit 
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 

    $errors = array(); // Initialize error array. 

    // Geef hier zoveel mogelijk vereiste velden voor validatie
    //Add attachment
    if(is_array($_FILES)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']
    ['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
    }

    // Controleer naam 
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z[:space:]]{2,}$/", $_POST['naam'])) { 
      $errors[] = 'Naam'; 
    }

    // Controleer adres 
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z[:space:]]{1,}$/", $_POST['straat'])) { 
    $errors[] = 'Adres'; 
    } 

    // Controleer huisnummer
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,4}$/", $_POST['huisnummer'])) { 
    $errors[] = 'Huisnummer'; 
    }

    // Controleer postcode
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST['postcode'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Postcode (Cijfers)'; 
    }

    // Controleer postcode letters
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/", $_POST['letters'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Postcode (Letters)'; 
    }

    // Controleer woonplaats
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z[:space:]]{2,}$/", $_POST['woonplaats'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Woonplaats'; 
    }

    // Controleer Kengetal 
    if (!preg_match("/^[0]{1}[0-9]{1,3}$/", $_POST['kengetal'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Kengetal'; 
    }

    // Controleer telefoonnummer 
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{6,8}$/", $_POST['telefoon'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Telefoonnummer'; 
    }

    // Controleer e-mail adres 
    if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$/", $_POST['email'])) { 
      $errors[] = 'E-mail adres'; 
    } 

    // Controleer tekstvak
    if (empty($_POST['bericht'])) { 
      $errors[] = 'Bericht'; 
    } 

    if (empty($errors)) {

    // Voer hier de gegevens in

    $mailFrom = "myEmail";
    $mailTo = "myEmail";
    $senderNaam = $_POST['naam'];
    $senderEmail = $_POST['email']; 
    $subject = 'mySubject';

    $okMessage = '<p>blablabla</p>';
    $errorMessage = '<p>blablabla</p>';

    $emailText .= "Naam: " . $_POST['titel']." ". $_POST['naam']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Bedrijfsnaam: " . $_POST['bedrijfsnaam']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Adres: " . $_POST['straat']." ". $_POST['huisnummer']." ". $_POST['toevoeging']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Postcode: " . $_POST['postcode']." ". $_POST['letters']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Woonplaats: " . $_POST['woonplaats']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Telefoonnummer: " . $_POST['kengetal']." ". $_POST['telefoon']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "E-mailadres: " . $_POST['email']. "\n";
    $emailText .= "Bericht: " . $_POST['bericht']. "\n";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'SMTP SERVER';            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'User';               // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'Pass';                        // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                   // TCP port to connect to


    $mail->Sender = $mailFrom;
    $mail->SetFrom($senderEmail, $senderNaam);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($senderEmail, $senderNaam);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($emailText);
    $mail->AddAddress($mailTo, $mailTo);
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file'); **// ADDED THIS HERE**


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = "<table>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Naam:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['titel']." ".$_POST['naam']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['bedrijfsnaam']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Adres:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['straat']." ".$_POST['huisnummer']." ".$_POST['toevoeging']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Postcode:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['postcode']." ".$_POST['letters']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Woonplaats:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['woonplaats']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Telefoonnummer:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['kengetal']." ".$_POST['telefoon']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>E-mailadres:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Bericht:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['bericht']."</td></tr>
                </table>";

    $mail->AltBody = $emailText;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
        } else {
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
            }
        }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo $encoded;
        } else {
        echo $responseArray['message'];
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Also added this to `<form>` enctype="multipart/form-data"

Edit #2: I also have a contact.js file with this:

`data: $(this).serialize(),`
I changed it in this:
`data:  new FormData(this),`
Because i read somewhere that this could be the problem, but it didnt make sense.

Comment: Your code looks ok. To see how to handle a file upload, look at [the example code provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). One other thing - don't use the submitter's address as the from address; it's forgery and will cause SPF failures. Put your own address as the form address, and use the submitter's as a reply-to (as you're doing).

Comment: Actually im not really good at this. So i dont know where to place what where.

Comment: You’re going to need to actually try; your existing code is nearly there, so look at the differences between it and what is in the example I pointed you at.

Comment: Alright, i made an edit above. It does send, but it doesnt send the attachment. No idea whats going wrong.

Comment: For the record... I want people to send me a file, and not a file to them when they send it.

Comment: The only difference between those options is who the email is sent to.

Comment: Well i dont understand you sorry. I have a form and i want an option where people can upload a file which will be attached in the email i receive in my mailbox. Is this possible? If so.. please tell me how.

Comment: The example I pointed you at does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Well i tried it, but the attachment was not with my email. The text in it was ok, but nothing was attached. I also tried [https://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-contact-form-with-attachment-using-php] this one, but it stays the same, nothing attached.

Comment: Solve one problem at a time - make sure your form submission works correctly first (point it at a script doing nothing but `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)`), *then* look at your PHP. Check every stage - is your uploaded file moved successfully (the example checks for this)? Does the call to `addAttachment` work correctly (i.e. does it return `true`)? I'd recommend using the example script and running it in a debugger so you can step through it - search for how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the form is sending with attachments! There is only one little thing i hope someone can help me with that.. more about this later on. First the code.

In contact.js - I had to change `data: $(this).serialize(),` into `data:  new FormData(this),`

```
    $(function () {

        $('#contact-form').validator();

        $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                var url = "send.php";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data:  new FormData(this),
                    cache       : false,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                        var messageText = data.message;

                        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                        if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                            $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();  //Remove this line if form should not reset after submit
                            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#contact-form').offset().top}, 'fast'); //Remove this line if form should not scroll to top of the form after submit
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
```

Myform.html - 2 things: this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>`, and this

```
    <!--attachments-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="attachment">Attachment</label>                                            
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile">
      </div>
```

somewhere you want in the form.

Finally put this in your phpmailer file:

```
    //Add attachment
    if(is_array($_FILES)) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
    }
```

I did it below `$mail->AddAddress($mailTo, $mailTo);`

So far how to fix this. There is still one problem left i refer to in the beginning.

**Without** `data:  new FormData(this),` I still get my okMessage (with markup) when i hit send and the form stays at the same page.

**With** `data:  new FormData(this),` it goes to a new page and just give black on white plain text (without markup). 
So its like FormData is overruling something. Hope someone can help me out with this.

EDIT: Seems i have fixed this too. Place this..

```
cache       : false,
contentType : false,
processData : false,
```

..below `data:  new FormData(this),`